# How to search parentheses, brackets using FULL TEXT INDEXING

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-indexing

I have been fighting this issue for a while

I would like to use a FULL Text Seach query to find Files on a windows file system.

The problem is when the case comes up where there is a parentheses in the file name.
This example was created from a copy being pasted in the same location as the original a few times.

Here is my code:

`DECLARE  @SearchWord VARCHAR(50)
SET @SearchWord = '"KAP1556PP_P01(2).jpg"'
    SELECT 
        [FileName],
        [FilePath]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[tblLegalPlan] 
    WHERE 
        CONTAINS(*, @SearchWord)`

When I use Double quotes for the @Searchword I recieve no results.

When I use no quotes for the @Searchword I recieve an error message:

```
Msg 7630, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
Syntax error near '(' in the full-text search condition 'KAP1556PP_P01(2).jpg'.
```

When I search for files containing TEXT up to the bracket i Get undesrired results obviously:

```
SET @SearchWord = '"KAP1556PP_P01*"'
```

Results

```
FileName                FilePath
KAP1556PP_P01(1).jpg    BC\EPP\KAP
KAP1556PP_P01(2).jpg    BC\EPP\KAP
```

Any and all iterations of the above show to not be usefull.
There are many articles of people trying to parse the search terms and work it out, but I have not come accross any that can handle this situation.
A solution would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around to this for me was to execute a Stored Procedure that would remove and/or replace the brackets in question, allowing the FULL TEXT indexing to work.